# How to delete an undesirable row from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe for exemple like :

```
id       column1       column2
1        aaa           mmm
2        bbb           nnn
3        ccc           ooo
4        ddd           ppp
5        eee           qqq
```

I have a list that contain some values from column1 :

```
[bbb],[ddd],[eee]
```

I need python code in order to delete from the pandas all elements existing in the list

Ps: my pandas contains 280 000 samples so I need a fast code

Thanks

Comment: `[bbb],[ddd],[eee]` is not a list. How does your list look like?

Comment: Read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my list is generated based on : my_list = df_list["user_id"].tolist()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isin and its negation (~):

```
df[~df.column1.isin(['bbb','ddd', 'eee'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df = df.loc[~df['B'].isin(list), :]`